# UIAlertView memory issues

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, uialertview, instruments

I have created a very simple iPhone application, with single view and a UIButton with action to show UIAlertView.
I am using following code

```
- (IBAction)showAlert:(id)sender {
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
     [alert show];
     [alert release];
}
```

Instruments allocations tool screen shot is attached.
[image]

In the image,low  memory allocations shows app running without showing `UIAlertView`, and high peaks shows memory usage after i have shown `UIAlertView`, even i have dismissed `UIAlertView` and release it but it continues to show same memory state and living objects (as high as 50,000). but when i press home button app goes in background and you can see in attached image living objects and used memory decrease.

Questions:

Whats wrong with my code?

Why even after releasing `UIAlertView` it shows high memory allocation and living objects?

Why i have to go to background to release memory and living objects?

Answer (score 1):

I would not worry too much about it, unless this is the major memory bottleneck in your app, or unless each UIAlertView cumulatively adds more memory.

Your code is correct. But even though you release the UIAlertView, the user interface system holds on to it at least until you dismiss the alert. In addition to the UIAlertView itself, it also allocates graphics resources needed to show the alert. After you dismiss the alert, it depends on when the autorelease loop kicks in, and on caching parameters, whether and when the memory gets released.

When you push the home button, then your application goes to the background, and as part of that memory deallocation is forced. That is, caches are emptied, autorelease cycle is run, etc.

Comment: Actually i am working on other app, where i am doing memory optimization using instruments tool, and uialertview increases living objects considerably and don't decrease in usage until i press home button. So i want to solve this issue.

Comment: I got curious, so wrote a small test program. In my tests, only the first UIAlertView increases the memory, not any additional ones. And the increase is only 250k, so not anything to worry about. Possibly it caches the background image of the UIAlertView, for example.

Comment: Yes first increases, but not decreases no matter how much time you spend on app. In my test app, living bytes before first UIAlertView show is 670KB (8285 living objects) and after show of the alert living bytes are 3.50MB (48,000 living objects)

Comment: And as i said in my question test app is simple one view app with only 1 button but see the figures i posted in above comments its alarming and i don't know how to handle this

Comment: I am testing on iOS 6.1.3 iPhone 4S with Xcode 4.6.1 and Insturment 4.6.

Comment: I still don't see it as alarming. To put the figures you post into perspective: the increase you report (2.8M) is about the same memory size as a single full screen image. If you are really that concerned about it, write a bug report to Apple.

Comment: Oh, i just checked on iOS 5 and there is no issue at all. :(

Comment: I am facing the same problem. To make the matter worse when you use a textbox inside the alert view and start typing into it, god it just starts to use memory like hungry. I dont know what to do with this.

Comment: @MuhammadNasir UIAlertView does not allow a textbox inside the alert view, so you must be using it in an unsupported way. I'd suggest trying some of the replacements available on the web, such as https://github.com/siriusdely/SMAlertView